# Mysql Union with PHP PDO - How get Data in Variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, union

I have the following MySQL Code that runs fine and PHP code that I've used before. The catch is I can't seem to get the output into variables:

```
    $sql='SELECT COUNT(pid) AS konnectMainStats FROM a
                UNION
                SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM b WHERE photo_name IS NOT NULL AND photo_name <> ""
                UNION
                SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM c;';
    $pds=$database_users->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array()); $rows=$pds->fetchAll();


    $this->totalRelationships = number_format($rows[0]);
```

I know the query is fine as it returns 3 values as the images shows:

[image]

How do I get these values into 3 unique variables so I can use them?

I can give more info if need & thankyou :)

Comment: Instead of having UNION; select each of them as a separate columns (and thereby, making this question MySQL specific instead of PHP/PDO).

Comment: thank you... I have switched to separate select columns... great idea and greatly appreciated...